# How to avoid physical path in swt filedialog

Tags: linux, eclipse-plugin, swt

I'm writing a plugin for Eclipse. The plugin is intended to run on Linux. In one of the wizard, we are using FileDialog with `setFilterPath("/xx/yy/zz")`; When I run the plugin, the file browser goes to `"/aa/bb/cc"` because `"/aa/bb/cc"` is the physical path of link `"/xx/yy/zz"`.
Though it is a link, it is misguiding the user. Is there any possibility to open browser with `"/xx/yy/zz"` path?

Thanks a million!

Comment: Could you elaborate on that? I find it hard to understand what you are asking for.

Comment: I think chintu means, that the `FileDialog` of SWT dereferences symbolic links (`ln -s`) on Linux. That means, that the dialog points to the "physical" (resolved) path. He expects that the FileDialog should point to the symbolic link. That's how I understand the question, anyway the question should be updated because it's very hard to understand.

Comment: There is a related bug report [here](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=33436).